# Polygon intersection giving a GeometryCollection of only LineStrings, and the wrong dimension

Tags: postgis, postgresql, intersection, ogc

I have a case where I want to create a difference between two geometries, and store it my db. I later need to check for conflict between geometries in the db, and for that I check two things: if there is an intersection, and if that intersection's dimension is at most one (Point, LineString, MultiLineString, and collections containing those).

The issue I get can be reproduced with the SQL below. I have a difference that is giving me a GeometryCollection even though it only contains LineStrings, and even weirder, its dimension is 2.

```sql
begin;

create table z (
    name text NOT NULL,
    geom geometry NOT NULL
);

insert into z values
    ('a', 'POLYGON((-0.8835662511166233 46.95026,-1.1673 46.95026,-1.1673 47.24754,-0.24445 47.24754,-0.24445 47.10458117771998,-0.255375 47.100286,-0.287925 47.101438,-0.298957 47.09925,-0.314251 47.091338,-0.33027 47.088981,-0.312555 47.092257,-0.311854 47.104175,-0.315605 47.105394,-0.314916 47.106305,-0.317185 47.108012,-0.318197 47.107497,-0.322738 47.108762,-0.322166 47.113341,-0.323874 47.116436,-0.321459 47.121283,-0.325581 47.123121,-0.327816 47.122427,-0.330002 47.123199,-0.3293 47.12564,-0.330249 47.126144,-0.332498 47.125027,-0.33722 47.12614,-0.338209 47.125162,-0.339118 47.125369,-0.339153 47.12661,-0.341232 47.128987,-0.337955 47.130561,-0.33382 47.130432,-0.332489 47.131577,-0.334297 47.132289,-0.333255 47.133742,-0.338095 47.134994,-0.342742 47.134635,-0.350545 47.13761,-0.353369 47.141311,-0.347566 47.146139,-0.348841 47.146936,-0.350786 47.146715,-0.350341 47.148346,-0.352047 47.151282,-0.351485 47.152225,-0.353323 47.152762,-0.35578 47.149185,-0.36114 47.151223,-0.366432 47.151314,-0.369563 47.153469,-0.375187 47.151642,-0.384412 47.156495,-0.396127 47.159938,-0.399628 47.159767,-0.40023 47.155858,-0.404906 47.160023,-0.410125 47.158827,-0.406628 47.163987,-0.394179 47.171043,-0.38967 47.175879,-0.394587 47.176119,-0.397269 47.174935,-0.399488 47.177426,-0.402195 47.177222,-0.407773 47.179534,-0.413784 47.180231,-0.411807 47.183143,-0.411996 47.185065,-0.412716 47.185433,-0.412285 47.187333,-0.413439 47.187417,-0.413958 47.190365,-0.417619 47.190956,-0.418248 47.193134,-0.418511 47.195844,-0.412792 47.200155,-0.412285 47.201901,-0.409833 47.204575,-0.41171 47.205248,-0.410264 47.206932,-0.407826 47.206784,-0.405048 47.210537,-0.40383 47.213639,-0.401814 47.215326,-0.401168 47.219627,-0.408793 47.219609,-0.417328 47.223194,-0.421213 47.223417,-0.423234 47.221124,-0.42749 47.218448,-0.430493 47.214774,-0.432012 47.215171,-0.436489 47.21435,-0.439494 47.215173,-0.443709 47.220465,-0.448277 47.221702,-0.454212 47.218059,-0.453324 47.216126,-0.455677 47.211151,-0.461469 47.206421,-0.46267 47.206468,-0.473101 47.197326,-0.476512 47.198431,-0.478934 47.198011,-0.480203 47.199556,-0.48129 47.199278,-0.482276 47.200104,-0.483332 47.20406,-0.480932 47.206143,-0.479899 47.208412,-0.48982 47.2108,-0.493161 47.210967,-0.495366 47.210041,-0.497523 47.211184,-0.500894 47.20962,-0.506224 47.209061,-0.518344 47.210022,-0.533786 47.207824,-0.544078 47.207204,-0.547078 47.208665,-0.550243 47.20432,-0.555934 47.200523,-0.555665 47.199108,-0.557256 47.197598,-0.558835 47.194163,-0.565194 47.192525,-0.571555 47.189365,-0.581188 47.180057,-0.589552 47.175159,-0.590948 47.173115,-0.5911419999999999 47.169356,-0.593306 47.166566,-0.596559 47.163645,-0.598875 47.159885,-0.60299 47.157147,-0.606321 47.153981,-0.6064310000000001 47.153063,-0.608714 47.151739,-0.611255 47.147944,-0.614066 47.148949,-0.634778 47.151401,-0.636791 47.151277,-0.637368 47.149049,-0.641321 47.15116,-0.6429009999999999 47.150853,-0.645837 47.148712,-0.648111 47.148068,-0.648071 47.146159,-0.6502289999999999 47.144351,-0.650943 47.144014,-0.650964 47.14514,-0.655204 47.144456,-0.655244 47.141967,-0.65679 47.140824,-0.657742 47.141094,-0.657647 47.141996,-0.6591669999999999 47.141034,-0.660958 47.141474,-0.661645 47.142495,-0.662358 47.13973,-0.660788 47.138781,-0.661117 47.137602,-0.659606 47.136733,-0.666837 47.133182,-0.6700739999999999 47.134202,-0.671374 47.132367,-0.678609 47.129982,-0.679654 47.130824,-0.685009 47.131849,-0.688837 47.129736,-0.6924630000000001 47.129899,-0.694172 47.130908,-0.696088 47.129613,-0.699315 47.1292,-0.7014899999999999 47.127601,-0.701852 47.130356,-0.703497 47.131179,-0.705908 47.131881,-0.706937 47.130723,-0.7106 47.13282,-0.715656 47.132769,-0.719769 47.130794,-0.719932 47.128783,-0.722145 47.128122,-0.726214 47.127882,-0.727239 47.1286,-0.7403110000000001 47.130005,-0.743658 47.127853,-0.747465 47.126936,-0.753305 47.128401,-0.755615 47.126224,-0.757279 47.129441,-0.764166 47.130843,-0.765193 47.13241,-0.7646810000000001 47.137155,-0.765204 47.138177,-0.76298 47.14355,-0.775934 47.142725,-0.776545 47.14425,-0.784825 47.142603,-0.785197 47.146892,-0.786251 47.146968,-0.788176 47.149197,-0.789696 47.147616,-0.790662 47.148312,-0.792366 47.147384,-0.796446 47.14782,-0.79675 47.150273,-0.798743 47.152046,-0.7999000000000001 47.151605,-0.8017 47.153203,-0.802353 47.157038,-0.805691 47.156591,-0.808284 47.157468,-0.8180539999999999 47.154176,-0.821728 47.15623,-0.825337 47.156855,-0.827803 47.152363,-0.830325 47.152719,-0.831657 47.150077,-0.836781 47.150523,-0.839548 47.149972,-0.851464 47.152844,-0.855811 47.152801,-0.860479 47.151358,-0.863144 47.151598,-0.866328 47.154278,-0.866803 47.156878,-0.874066 47.158261,-0.875957 47.159696,-0.877381 47.158906,-0.879756 47.159392,-0.885042 47.158851,-0.888682 47.160368,-0.895814 47.161263,-0.899084 47.160432,-0.902938 47.161005,-0.90419 47.160098,-0.904825 47.161118,-0.906819 47.161096,-0.908851 47.160224,-0.911125 47.164967,-0.912727 47.164685,-0.910135 47.159648,-0.911496 47.159322,-0.918746 47.159644,-0.926071 47.163675,-0.927214 47.162774,-0.92893 47.162757,-0.934443 47.160325,-0.937325 47.157219,-0.938397 47.157361,-0.940798 47.154856,-0.940044 47.153671,-0.942047 47.153084,-0.941596 47.152113,-0.944796 47.151628,-0.944708 47.149874,-0.948285 47.149339,-0.955456 47.144794,-0.955037 47.144178,-0.956323 47.139477,-0.957614 47.13712,-0.956129 47.13727,-0.956686 47.136964,-0.954873 47.135147,-0.948601 47.132549,-0.948274 47.131818,-0.950375 47.129795,-0.946984 47.127447,-0.948981 47.125865,-0.948527 47.124269,-0.951528 47.123316,-0.952133 47.120092,-0.9461889999999999 47.120618,-0.946038 47.119935,-0.949882 47.117637,-0.950936 47.115496,-0.9536829999999999 47.114413,-0.95651 47.11443,-0.961096 47.116071,-0.965263 47.115767,-0.964548 47.114124,-0.9672539999999999 47.109873,-0.96705 47.108872,-0.967849 47.107754,-0.970367 47.106898,-0.96872 47.105441,-0.966329 47.104755,-0.969109 47.101294,-0.978438 47.100071,-0.979903 47.096908,-0.984779 47.094839,-0.989408 47.091092,-0.9921 47.09038,-0.99311 47.089019,-0.997895 47.09084,-0.9984960000000001 47.088622,-0.997505 47.086696,-0.998069 47.085131,-0.996599 47.08316,-1.001639 47.082483,-1.004834 47.080101,-1.008233 47.080038,-1.012071 47.07765,-1.013411 47.075481,-1.017289 47.074766,-1.023597 47.077407,-1.026835 47.077853,-1.030644 47.072867,-1.032601 47.071583,-1.032856 47.070107,-1.038363 47.068104,-1.038371 47.067549,-1.039566 47.067823,-1.035791 47.070638,-1.039291 47.07315,-1.041014 47.073183,-1.046194 47.068615,-1.042919 47.063977,-1.04296 47.059505,-1.03872 47.061387,-1.031558 47.055852,-1.040741 47.052037,-1.042479 47.052727,-1.043862 47.052359,-1.041309 47.050274,-1.040363 47.048076,-1.040996 47.047222,-1.038031 47.045406,-1.033921 47.044428,-1.028526 47.046577,-1.028338 47.043193,-1.023855 47.042567,-1.023727 47.044304,-1.022619 47.044506,-1.020078 47.042246,-1.020713 47.0395,-1.018823 47.038146,-1.020219 47.0374,-1.017553 47.03602,-1.011849 47.034329,-1.011117 47.034892,-1.012478 47.036518,-1.012062 47.037209,-1.010507 47.036397,-1.008813 47.037094,-1.005892 47.034645,-1.003499 47.034155,-1.00369 47.029205,-1.008565 47.027608,-1.005871 47.027086,-1.003761 47.02556,-1.001848 47.027837,-1.000034 47.027594,-0.995461 47.024415,-0.9974229999999999 47.022981,-1.000446 47.022611,-0.999402 47.025138,-1.000672 47.02556,-1.002044 47.024403,-1.000567 47.022544,-1.002179 47.02152,-0.999529 47.020687,-0.995514 47.017676,-0.982174 47.010593,-0.980279 47.014309,-0.982976 47.016083,-0.981502 47.017046,-0.981873 47.018124,-0.9783539999999999 47.018918,-0.976156 47.018317,-0.9756629999999999 47.01687,-0.973361 47.016124,-0.975314 47.013218,-0.973166 47.012531,-0.974932 47.010525,-0.975229 47.008652,-0.973483 47.008101,-0.972909 47.009056,-0.970504 47.007588,-0.967816 47.007355,-0.968678 47.006687,-0.965982 47.004729,-0.967052 47.005199,-0.968005 47.004208,-0.966535 47.002838,-0.964014 47.003068,-0.963229 47.001985,-0.963101 47.00063,-0.964984 46.999584,-0.9634470000000001 46.998099,-0.964354 46.997292,-0.963159 46.996458,-0.961741 46.997277,-0.962158 46.995809,-0.959851 46.995287,-0.960803 46.994723,-0.957388 46.994887,-0.9582850000000001 46.99543,-0.9567369999999999 46.996404,-0.954756 46.995966,-0.955661 46.99757,-0.95504 46.999919,-0.953334 47.000764,-0.951958 47.002736,-0.947959 47.003694,-0.948313 47.001307,-0.947166 46.999717,-0.944993 46.998988,-0.941698 47.00358,-0.9402779999999999 47.003189,-0.939812 47.002193,-0.939634 47.002783,-0.938673 47.002401,-0.9385289999999999 47.0034,-0.937296 47.003048,-0.936462 47.005257,-0.934844 47.005633,-0.935539 47.007348,-0.933399 47.009041,-0.9329499999999999 47.007838,-0.932015 47.007985,-0.932389 47.006069,-0.929194 47.008111,-0.927473 47.006346,-0.928248 47.00382,-0.9310389999999999 47.004519,-0.931063 47.003357,-0.9327800000000001 47.00456,-0.935226 47.002345,-0.928661 47.002451,-0.928445 47.000682,-0.925042 46.999834,-0.925021 47.002535,-0.919706 47.003377,-0.919365 47.002324,-0.915853 47.001637,-0.914871 47.000633,-0.916957 46.999858,-0.9179580000000001 46.998454,-0.921435 46.998028,-0.918685 46.996536,-0.918747 46.995522,-0.916525 46.996111,-0.914227 46.994688,-0.915649 46.993302,-0.915289 46.992611,-0.912311 46.992815,-0.910853 46.994271,-0.912372 46.995659,-0.9117 46.995997,-0.908708 46.99287,-0.907873 46.994955,-0.904396 46.994915,-0.902515 46.993922,-0.90103 46.991734,-0.8974839999999999 46.989799,-0.898968 46.988701,-0.895404 46.986335,-0.89623 46.985842,-0.8957270000000001 46.985249,-0.893065 46.984496,-0.8968429999999999 46.980815,-0.8948739999999999 46.980231,-0.8950709999999999 46.979177,-0.8924840000000001 46.978577,-0.892187 46.976082,-0.89028 46.975818,-0.891964 46.97582,-0.88901 46.970996,-0.877125 46.968538,-0.883595 46.962369,-0.877139 46.955856,-0.8837970000000001 46.950389,-0.8835662511166233 46.95026))'),
    ('b', 'POLYGON((-1.003499 47.034155,-1.005892 47.034645,-1.008813 47.037094,-1.010507 47.036397,-1.012062 47.037209,-1.012478 47.036518,-1.011117 47.034892,-1.011849 47.034329,-1.017553 47.03602,-1.020219 47.0374,-1.018823 47.038146,-1.020713 47.0395,-1.020078 47.042246,-1.022619 47.044506,-1.023727 47.044304,-1.023855 47.042567,-1.028338 47.043193,-1.028526 47.046577,-1.033921 47.044428,-1.038031 47.045406,-1.040996 47.047222,-1.040363 47.048076,-1.041309 47.050274,-1.043862 47.052359,-1.042479 47.052727,-1.040741 47.052037,-1.031558 47.055852,-1.03872 47.061387,-1.04296 47.059505,-1.042919 47.063977,-1.046194 47.068615,-1.041014 47.073183,-1.039291 47.07315,-1.035791 47.070638,-1.039566 47.067823,-1.038371 47.067549,-1.038363 47.068104,-1.032856 47.070107,-1.032601 47.071583,-1.030644 47.072867,-1.026835 47.077853,-1.023597 47.077407,-1.017289 47.074766,-1.013411 47.075481,-1.012071 47.07765,-1.008233 47.080038,-1.004834 47.080101,-1.001639 47.082483,-0.996599 47.08316,-0.998069 47.085131,-0.997505 47.086696,-0.9984960000000001 47.088622,-0.997895 47.09084,-0.99311 47.089019,-0.9921 47.09038,-0.989408 47.091092,-0.984779 47.094839,-0.979903 47.096908,-0.978438 47.100071,-0.969109 47.101294,-0.966329 47.104755,-0.96872 47.105441,-0.970367 47.106898,-0.967849 47.107754,-0.96705 47.108872,-0.9672539999999999 47.109873,-0.964548 47.114124,-0.965263 47.115767,-0.961096 47.116071,-0.95651 47.11443,-0.9536829999999999 47.114413,-0.950936 47.115496,-0.949882 47.117637,-0.946038 47.119935,-0.9461889999999999 47.120618,-0.952133 47.120092,-0.951528 47.123316,-0.948527 47.124269,-0.948981 47.125865,-0.946984 47.127447,-0.950375 47.129795,-0.948274 47.131818,-0.948601 47.132549,-0.954873 47.135147,-0.956686 47.136964,-0.956129 47.13727,-0.957614 47.13712,-0.956323 47.139477,-0.955037 47.144178,-0.955456 47.144794,-0.948285 47.149339,-0.944708 47.149874,-0.944796 47.151628,-0.941596 47.152113,-0.942047 47.153084,-0.940044 47.153671,-0.940798 47.154856,-0.938397 47.157361,-0.937325 47.157219,-0.934443 47.160325,-0.92893 47.162757,-0.927214 47.162774,-0.926071 47.163675,-0.918746 47.159644,-0.911496 47.159322,-0.910135 47.159648,-0.912727 47.164685,-0.911125 47.164967,-0.908851 47.160224,-0.906819 47.161096,-0.904825 47.161118,-0.90419 47.160098,-0.902938 47.161005,-0.899084 47.160432,-0.895814 47.161263,-0.888682 47.160368,-0.885042 47.158851,-0.879756 47.159392,-0.877381 47.158906,-0.875957 47.159696,-0.874066 47.158261,-0.866803 47.156878,-0.866328 47.154278,-0.863144 47.151598,-0.860479 47.151358,-0.855811 47.152801,-0.851464 47.152844,-0.839548 47.149972,-0.836781 47.150523,-0.831657 47.150077,-0.830325 47.152719,-0.827803 47.152363,-0.825337 47.156855,-0.821728 47.15623,-0.8180539999999999 47.154176,-0.808284 47.157468,-0.805691 47.156591,-0.802353 47.157038,-0.8017 47.153203,-0.7999000000000001 47.151605,-0.798743 47.152046,-0.79675 47.150273,-0.796446 47.14782,-0.792366 47.147384,-0.790662 47.148312,-0.789696 47.147616,-0.788176 47.149197,-0.786251 47.146968,-0.785197 47.146892,-0.784825 47.142603,-0.776545 47.14425,-0.775934 47.142725,-0.76298 47.14355,-0.765204 47.138177,-0.7646810000000001 47.137155,-0.765193 47.13241,-0.764166 47.130843,-0.757279 47.129441,-0.755615 47.126224,-0.753305 47.128401,-0.747465 47.126936,-0.743658 47.127853,-0.7403110000000001 47.130005,-0.727239 47.1286,-0.726214 47.127882,-0.722145 47.128122,-0.719932 47.128783,-0.719769 47.130794,-0.715656 47.132769,-0.7106 47.13282,-0.706937 47.130723,-0.705908 47.131881,-0.703497 47.131179,-0.701852 47.130356,-0.7014899999999999 47.127601,-0.699315 47.1292,-0.696088 47.129613,-0.694172 47.130908,-0.6924630000000001 47.129899,-0.688837 47.129736,-0.685009 47.131849,-0.679654 47.130824,-0.678609 47.129982,-0.671374 47.132367,-0.6700739999999999 47.134202,-0.666837 47.133182,-0.659606 47.136733,-0.661117 47.137602,-0.660788 47.138781,-0.662358 47.13973,-0.661645 47.142495,-0.660958 47.141474,-0.6591669999999999 47.141034,-0.657647 47.141996,-0.657742 47.141094,-0.65679 47.140824,-0.655244 47.141967,-0.655204 47.144456,-0.650964 47.14514,-0.650943 47.144014,-0.6502289999999999 47.144351,-0.648071 47.146159,-0.648111 47.148068,-0.645837 47.148712,-0.6429009999999999 47.150853,-0.641321 47.15116,-0.637368 47.149049,-0.636791 47.151277,-0.634778 47.151401,-0.614066 47.148949,-0.611255 47.147944,-0.608714 47.151739,-0.6064310000000001 47.153063,-0.606321 47.153981,-0.60299 47.157147,-0.598875 47.159885,-0.596559 47.163645,-0.593306 47.166566,-0.5911419999999999 47.169356,-0.590948 47.173115,-0.589552 47.175159,-0.581188 47.180057,-0.571555 47.189365,-0.565194 47.192525,-0.558835 47.194163,-0.557256 47.197598,-0.555665 47.199108,-0.555934 47.200523,-0.550243 47.20432,-0.547078 47.208665,-0.544078 47.207204,-0.533786 47.207824,-0.518344 47.210022,-0.506224 47.209061,-0.500894 47.20962,-0.497523 47.211184,-0.495366 47.210041,-0.493161 47.210967,-0.48982 47.2108,-0.479899 47.208412,-0.480932 47.206143,-0.483332 47.20406,-0.482276 47.200104,-0.48129 47.199278,-0.480203 47.199556,-0.478934 47.198011,-0.476512 47.198431,-0.473101 47.197326,-0.46267 47.206468,-0.461469 47.206421,-0.455677 47.211151,-0.453324 47.216126,-0.454212 47.218059,-0.448277 47.221702,-0.443709 47.220465,-0.439494 47.215173,-0.436489 47.21435,-0.432012 47.215171,-0.430493 47.214774,-0.42749 47.218448,-0.423234 47.221124,-0.421213 47.223417,-0.417328 47.223194,-0.408793 47.219609,-0.401168 47.219627,-0.401814 47.215326,-0.40383 47.213639,-0.405048 47.210537,-0.407826 47.206784,-0.410264 47.206932,-0.41171 47.205248,-0.409833 47.204575,-0.412285 47.201901,-0.412792 47.200155,-0.418511 47.195844,-0.418248 47.193134,-0.417619 47.190956,-0.413958 47.190365,-0.413439 47.187417,-0.412285 47.187333,-0.412716 47.185433,-0.411996 47.185065,-0.411807 47.183143,-0.413784 47.180231,-0.407773 47.179534,-0.402195 47.177222,-0.399488 47.177426,-0.397269 47.174935,-0.394587 47.176119,-0.38967 47.175879,-0.394179 47.171043,-0.406628 47.163987,-0.410125 47.158827,-0.404906 47.160023,-0.40023 47.155858,-0.399628 47.159767,-0.396127 47.159938,-0.384412 47.156495,-0.375187 47.151642,-0.369563 47.153469,-0.366432 47.151314,-0.36114 47.151223,-0.35578 47.149185,-0.353323 47.152762,-0.351485 47.152225,-0.352047 47.151282,-0.350341 47.148346,-0.350786 47.146715,-0.348841 47.146936,-0.347566 47.146139,-0.353369 47.141311,-0.350545 47.13761,-0.342742 47.134635,-0.338095 47.134994,-0.333255 47.133742,-0.334297 47.132289,-0.332489 47.131577,-0.33382 47.130432,-0.337955 47.130561,-0.341232 47.128987,-0.339153 47.12661,-0.339118 47.125369,-0.338209 47.125162,-0.33722 47.12614,-0.332498 47.125027,-0.330249 47.126144,-0.3293 47.12564,-0.330002 47.123199,-0.327816 47.122427,-0.325581 47.123121,-0.321459 47.121283,-0.323874 47.116436,-0.322166 47.113341,-0.322738 47.108762,-0.318197 47.107497,-0.317185 47.108012,-0.314916 47.106305,-0.315605 47.105394,-0.311854 47.104175,-0.312555 47.092257,-0.335593 47.087996,-0.341764 47.087377,-0.342071 47.089257,-0.340917 47.092061,-0.349764 47.091708,-0.353789 47.095386,-0.359845 47.093259,-0.368792 47.091703,-0.370858 47.090185,-0.376532 47.088641,-0.380109 47.09001,-0.381368 47.08822,-0.384549 47.087401,-0.386349 47.087343,-0.387114 47.092276,-0.396159 47.091638,-0.396735 47.08308,-0.400268 47.074938,-0.401197 47.070748,-0.407124 47.066498,-0.409291 47.066201,-0.417558 47.070664,-0.418326 47.071955,-0.423197 47.069714,-0.424254 47.071464,-0.425664 47.07098,-0.425819 47.072494,-0.426981 47.072988,-0.438973 47.069898,-0.439206 47.068855,-0.441123 47.067722,-0.45469 47.067357,-0.458225 47.068988,-0.460605 47.06816,-0.461078 47.068813,-0.465024 47.066888,-0.471237 47.059795,-0.472096 47.057572,-0.476341 47.054362,-0.48032 47.053338,-0.485332 47.063885,-0.484992 47.065973,-0.478094 47.071911,-0.472027 47.072332,-0.469805 47.073652,-0.468249 47.073194,-0.464185 47.074359,-0.463973 47.076088,-0.458991 47.079943,-0.459531 47.082046,-0.464456 47.081975,-0.468364 47.083816,-0.473271 47.081777,-0.476073 47.083041,-0.478752 47.081727,-0.484783 47.081687,-0.487739 47.080881,-0.490791 47.082896,-0.493101 47.083353,-0.504174 47.079332,-0.507317 47.079241,-0.511785 47.077466,-0.51525 47.078035,-0.525741 47.073919,-0.535313 47.0722,-0.544635 47.068135,-0.546309 47.066274,-0.557553 47.06409,-0.559461 47.061813,-0.5567 47.060691,-0.5543709999999999 47.05726,-0.558239 47.056069,-0.558275 47.053228,-0.556006 47.044378,-0.556265 47.042695,-0.548737 47.04057,-0.542042 47.034972,-0.542997 47.033622,-0.542336 47.032532,-0.54533 47.030668,-0.54581 47.029103,-0.547006 47.028835,-0.547965 47.029652,-0.551732 47.029048,-0.555679 47.030902,-0.562342 47.030496,-0.564087 47.026005,-0.563775 47.02414,-0.564869 47.020141,-0.569053 47.018291,-0.574987 47.017828,-0.580904 47.014612,-0.587014 47.009192,-0.586932 47.006709,-0.58775 47.005337,-0.594749 47.002794,-0.597171 47.000769,-0.593961 46.998759,-0.5954930000000001 46.99791,-0.601611 46.997764,-0.618781 46.992342,-0.621938 46.993911,-0.6249400000000001 46.992792,-0.624561 46.994115,-0.6279169999999999 46.995691,-0.6267430000000001 46.996879,-0.63266 46.997508,-0.6354379999999999 46.995724,-0.640352 46.996116,-0.641046 46.994672,-0.642167 46.994818,-0.645504 46.99212,-0.646962 46.992308,-0.646391 46.99368,-0.649992 46.994917,-0.648025 46.996594,-0.650398 46.997689,-0.653462 46.997772,-0.657311 46.999199,-0.657708 46.9986,-0.660979 46.998839,-0.661627 46.997686,-0.669937 47.000802,-0.670368 47.002636,-0.671843 47.003185,-0.674719 47.001621,-0.676179 47.001885,-0.676831 47.000296,-0.674732 46.999172,-0.676007 46.997074,-0.675567 46.996648,-0.68038 46.993238,-0.678529 46.992114,-0.677686 46.989976,-0.680188 46.987659,-0.6829809999999999 46.98842,-0.686887 46.988065,-0.689599 46.990414,-0.689629 46.993058,-0.693412 46.992411,-0.696663 46.994873,-0.698748 46.99461,-0.700809 46.992531,-0.70435 46.992196,-0.703637 46.991424,-0.704682 46.990212,-0.712202 46.986674,-0.715947 46.98402,-0.7181070000000001 46.987193,-0.72926 46.995934,-0.7325430000000001 46.997508,-0.739475 46.998787,-0.743405 47.000992,-0.743626 46.994335,-0.74298 46.992012,-0.747754 46.991537,-0.753551 46.992972,-0.756819 46.991958,-0.7615150000000001 46.992264,-0.76411 46.992997,-0.765475 46.994016,-0.76528 46.994815,-0.7670979999999999 46.995785,-0.768885 46.995031,-0.768693 46.998337,-0.767998 46.99898,-0.768472 47.001449,-0.769335 47.002974,-0.771352 47.003471,-0.772268 47.004577,-0.773718 47.004606,-0.776458 47.003002,-0.7780010000000001 47.00428,-0.779699 47.004275,-0.781774 47.002141,-0.783438 47.001813,-0.784541 47.002807,-0.784486 47.004214,-0.786724 47.005452,-0.78967 47.003752,-0.789635 47.002406,-0.791189 47.0001,-0.796264 46.996051,-0.800662 46.994378,-0.804104 46.99387,-0.807032 46.994405,-0.810871 46.991732,-0.809145 46.99059,-0.808373 46.991571,-0.805102 46.989541,-0.807346 46.988608,-0.808466 46.986718,-0.809551 46.988562,-0.812299 46.989251,-0.812597 46.990568,-0.815701 46.989765,-0.811339 46.991774,-0.811747 46.994549,-0.815426 46.993264,-0.817527 46.993124,-0.81869 46.994079,-0.826568 46.992643,-0.8363429999999999 46.985762,-0.839504 46.985428,-0.842993 46.990173,-0.846592 46.986729,-0.847436 46.986872,-0.847915 46.982014,-0.849641 46.981979,-0.857129 46.978461,-0.85654 46.977397,-0.8492420000000001 46.97382,-0.8526 46.971008,-0.854617 46.971188,-0.860658 46.968886,-0.861437 46.969427,-0.861169 46.970234,-0.862803 46.970306,-0.862043 46.971125,-0.863063 46.971487,-0.863054 46.972617,-0.866704 46.973134,-0.867239 46.972541,-0.868179 46.973273,-0.869896 46.972059,-0.872356 46.973921,-0.87925 46.974666,-0.880167 46.975259,-0.879569 46.976065,-0.882064 46.977455,-0.882176 46.976556,-0.884937 46.977334,-0.8851560000000001 46.976298,-0.886918 46.976492,-0.888462 46.975566,-0.892187 46.976082,-0.8924840000000001 46.978577,-0.8950709999999999 46.979177,-0.8948739999999999 46.980231,-0.8968429999999999 46.980815,-0.893065 46.984496,-0.8957270000000001 46.985249,-0.89623 46.985842,-0.895404 46.986335,-0.898968 46.988701,-0.8974839999999999 46.989799,-0.90103 46.991734,-0.902515 46.993922,-0.904396 46.994915,-0.907873 46.994955,-0.908708 46.99287,-0.9117 46.995997,-0.912372 46.995659,-0.910853 46.994271,-0.912311 46.992815,-0.915289 46.992611,-0.915649 46.993302,-0.914227 46.994688,-0.916525 46.996111,-0.918747 46.995522,-0.918685 46.996536,-0.921435 46.998028,-0.9179580000000001 46.998454,-0.916957 46.999858,-0.914871 47.000633,-0.915853 47.001637,-0.919365 47.002324,-0.919706 47.003377,-0.925021 47.002535,-0.925042 46.999834,-0.928445 47.000682,-0.928661 47.002451,-0.935226 47.002345,-0.9327800000000001 47.00456,-0.931063 47.003357,-0.9310389999999999 47.004519,-0.928248 47.00382,-0.927473 47.006346,-0.929194 47.008111,-0.932389 47.006069,-0.932015 47.007985,-0.9329499999999999 47.007838,-0.933399 47.009041,-0.935539 47.007348,-0.934844 47.005633,-0.936462 47.005257,-0.937296 47.003048,-0.9385289999999999 47.0034,-0.938673 47.002401,-0.939634 47.002783,-0.939812 47.002193,-0.9402779999999999 47.003189,-0.941698 47.00358,-0.944993 46.998988,-0.947166 46.999717,-0.948313 47.001307,-0.947959 47.003694,-0.951958 47.002736,-0.953334 47.000764,-0.95504 46.999919,-0.955661 46.99757,-0.954756 46.995966,-0.9567369999999999 46.996404,-0.9582850000000001 46.99543,-0.957388 46.994887,-0.960803 46.994723,-0.959851 46.995287,-0.962158 46.995809,-0.961741 46.997277,-0.963159 46.996458,-0.964354 46.997292,-0.9634470000000001 46.998099,-0.964984 46.999584,-0.963101 47.00063,-0.963229 47.001985,-0.964014 47.003068,-0.966535 47.002838,-0.968005 47.004208,-0.967052 47.005199,-0.965982 47.004729,-0.968678 47.006687,-0.967816 47.007355,-0.970504 47.007588,-0.972909 47.009056,-0.973483 47.008101,-0.975229 47.008652,-0.974932 47.010525,-0.973166 47.012531,-0.975314 47.013218,-0.973361 47.016124,-0.9756629999999999 47.01687,-0.976156 47.018317,-0.9783539999999999 47.018918,-0.981873 47.018124,-0.981502 47.017046,-0.982976 47.016083,-0.980279 47.014309,-0.982174 47.010593,-0.995514 47.017676,-0.999529 47.020687,-1.002179 47.02152,-1.000567 47.022544,-1.002044 47.024403,-1.000672 47.02556,-0.999402 47.025138,-1.000446 47.022611,-0.9974229999999999 47.022981,-0.995461 47.024415,-1.000034 47.027594,-1.001848 47.027837,-1.003761 47.02556,-1.005871 47.027086,-1.008565 47.027608,-1.00369 47.029205,-1.003499 47.034155))');

select
    st_intersection(st_difference(a.geom, b.geom), b.geom), -- a GEOMETRYCOLLECTION of 203 LINESTRINGs
    st_dimension(st_intersection(st_difference(a.geom, b.geom), b.geom)) -- 2
from z a, z b
where a.name = 'a' and b.name = 'b';

rollback;
```

However, as stated in [PostGIS documentation](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Dimension.html):

> [ST_Dimension] returns 0 for `POINT`, 1 for `LINESTRING`, 2 for POLYGON, and the largest dimension of the components of a `GEOMETRYCOLLECTION`

Hence my question is: is that a bug I should report somewhere, or is there something I overlooked?

```sql
$ select postgis_full_version();
POSTGIS="2.5.5" [EXTENSION] PGSQL="120" GEOS="3.8.1-CAPI-1.13.3" PROJ="Rel. 7.0.1, May 1st, 2020" GDAL="GDAL 3.1.4, released 2020/10/20" LIBXML="2.9.10" LIBJSON="0.14" LIBPROTOBUF="1.3.3" TOPOLOGY RASTER
```

<sub>**NOTE:** There is a bit more context [here](https://github.com/libgeos/geos/issues/454) if ever needed.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me this is not an issue with wrongly constructed collections as per your GitHub issue.

The `GEOMETRYCOLLECTION` has **459 members** (or 461 if the geometries are passed in in different order) and indeed contains **a single *Polygon*** (sliver), which is most likely due to floating point imprecision:

```
WITH
    z (name, geom) AS (
        VALUES
            ('a', 'POLYGON((-0.8835662511166233 46.95026,-1.1673 46.95026,-1.1673 47.24754,-0.24445 47.24754,-0.24445 47.10458117771998,-0.255375 47.100286,-0.287925 47.101438,-0.298957 47.09925,-0.314251 47.091338,-0.33027 47.088981,-0.312555 47.092257,-0.311854 47.104175,-0.315605 47.105394,-0.314916 47.106305,-0.317185 47.108012,-0.318197 47.107497,-0.322738 47.108762,-0.322166 47.113341,-0.323874 47.116436,-0.321459 47.121283,-0.325581 47.123121,-0.327816 47.122427,-0.330002 47.123199,-0.3293 47.12564,-0.330249 47.126144,-0.332498 47.125027,-0.33722 47.12614,-0.338209 47.125162,-0.339118 47.125369,-0.339153 47.12661,-0.341232 47.128987,-0.337955 47.130561,-0.33382 47.130432,-0.332489 47.131577,-0.334297 47.132289,-0.333255 47.133742,-0.338095 47.134994,-0.342742 47.134635,-0.350545 47.13761,-0.353369 47.141311,-0.347566 47.146139,-0.348841 47.146936,-0.350786 47.146715,-0.350341 47.148346,-0.352047 47.151282,-0.351485 47.152225,-0.353323 47.152762,-0.35578 47.149185,-0.36114 47.151223,-0.366432 47.151314,-0.369563 47.153469,-0.375187 47.151642,-0.384412 47.156495,-0.396127 47.159938,-0.399628 47.159767,-0.40023 47.155858,-0.404906 47.160023,-0.410125 47.158827,-0.406628 47.163987,-0.394179 47.171043,-0.38967 47.175879,-0.394587 47.176119,-0.397269 47.174935,-0.399488 47.177426,-0.402195 47.177222,-0.407773 47.179534,-0.413784 47.180231,-0.411807 47.183143,-0.411996 47.185065,-0.412716 47.185433,-0.412285 47.187333,-0.413439 47.187417,-0.413958 47.190365,-0.417619 47.190956,-0.418248 47.193134,-0.418511 47.195844,-0.412792 47.200155,-0.412285 47.201901,-0.409833 47.204575,-0.41171 47.205248,-0.410264 47.206932,-0.407826 47.206784,-0.405048 47.210537,-0.40383 47.213639,-0.401814 47.215326,-0.401168 47.219627,-0.408793 47.219609,-0.417328 47.223194,-0.421213 47.223417,-0.423234 47.221124,-0.42749 47.218448,-0.430493 47.214774,-0.432012 47.215171,-0.436489 47.21435,-0.439494 47.215173,-0.443709 47.220465,-0.448277 47.221702,-0.454212 47.218059,-0.453324 47.216126,-0.455677 47.211151,-0.461469 47.206421,-0.46267 47.206468,-0.473101 47.197326,-0.476512 47.198431,-0.478934 47.198011,-0.480203 47.199556,-0.48129 47.199278,-0.482276 47.200104,-0.483332 47.20406,-0.480932 47.206143,-0.479899 47.208412,-0.48982 47.2108,-0.493161 47.210967,-0.495366 47.210041,-0.497523 47.211184,-0.500894 47.20962,-0.506224 47.209061,-0.518344 47.210022,-0.533786 47.207824,-0.544078 47.207204,-0.547078 47.208665,-0.550243 47.20432,-0.555934 47.200523,-0.555665 47.199108,-0.557256 47.197598,-0.558835 47.194163,-0.565194 47.192525,-0.571555 47.189365,-0.581188 47.180057,-0.589552 47.175159,-0.590948 47.173115,-0.5911419999999999 47.169356,-0.593306 47.166566,-0.596559 47.163645,-0.598875 47.159885,-0.60299 47.157147,-0.606321 47.153981,-0.6064310000000001 47.153063,-0.608714 47.151739,-0.611255 47.147944,-0.614066 47.148949,-0.634778 47.151401,-0.636791 47.151277,-0.637368 47.149049,-0.641321 47.15116,-0.6429009999999999 47.150853,-0.645837 47.148712,-0.648111 47.148068,-0.648071 47.146159,-0.6502289999999999 47.144351,-0.650943 47.144014,-0.650964 47.14514,-0.655204 47.144456,-0.655244 47.141967,-0.65679 47.140824,-0.657742 47.141094,-0.657647 47.141996,-0.6591669999999999 47.141034,-0.660958 47.141474,-0.661645 47.142495,-0.662358 47.13973,-0.660788 47.138781,-0.661117 47.137602,-0.659606 47.136733,-0.666837 47.133182,-0.6700739999999999 47.134202,-0.671374 47.132367,-0.678609 47.129982,-0.679654 47.130824,-0.685009 47.131849,-0.688837 47.129736,-0.6924630000000001 47.129899,-0.694172 47.130908,-0.696088 47.129613,-0.699315 47.1292,-0.7014899999999999 47.127601,-0.701852 47.130356,-0.703497 47.131179,-0.705908 47.131881,-0.706937 47.130723,-0.7106 47.13282,-0.715656 47.132769,-0.719769 47.130794,-0.719932 47.128783,-0.722145 47.128122,-0.726214 47.127882,-0.727239 47.1286,-0.7403110000000001 47.130005,-0.743658 47.127853,-0.747465 47.126936,-0.753305 47.128401,-0.755615 47.126224,-0.757279 47.129441,-0.764166 47.130843,-0.765193 47.13241,-0.7646810000000001 47.137155,-0.765204 47.138177,-0.76298 47.14355,-0.775934 47.142725,-0.776545 47.14425,-0.784825 47.142603,-0.785197 47.146892,-0.786251 47.146968,-0.788176 47.149197,-0.789696 47.147616,-0.790662 47.148312,-0.792366 47.147384,-0.796446 47.14782,-0.79675 47.150273,-0.798743 47.152046,-0.7999000000000001 47.151605,-0.8017 47.153203,-0.802353 47.157038,-0.805691 47.156591,-0.808284 47.157468,-0.8180539999999999 47.154176,-0.821728 47.15623,-0.825337 47.156855,-0.827803 47.152363,-0.830325 47.152719,-0.831657 47.150077,-0.836781 47.150523,-0.839548 47.149972,-0.851464 47.152844,-0.855811 47.152801,-0.860479 47.151358,-0.863144 47.151598,-0.866328 47.154278,-0.866803 47.156878,-0.874066 47.158261,-0.875957 47.159696,-0.877381 47.158906,-0.879756 47.159392,-0.885042 47.158851,-0.888682 47.160368,-0.895814 47.161263,-0.899084 47.160432,-0.902938 47.161005,-0.90419 47.160098,-0.904825 47.161118,-0.906819 47.161096,-0.908851 47.160224,-0.911125 47.164967,-0.912727 47.164685,-0.910135 47.159648,-0.911496 47.159322,-0.918746 47.159644,-0.926071 47.163675,-0.927214 47.162774,-0.92893 47.162757,-0.934443 47.160325,-0.937325 47.157219,-0.938397 47.157361,-0.940798 47.154856,-0.940044 47.153671,-0.942047 47.153084,-0.941596 47.152113,-0.944796 47.151628,-0.944708 47.149874,-0.948285 47.149339,-0.955456 47.144794,-0.955037 47.144178,-0.956323 47.139477,-0.957614 47.13712,-0.956129 47.13727,-0.956686 47.136964,-0.954873 47.135147,-0.948601 47.132549,-0.948274 47.131818,-0.950375 47.129795,-0.946984 47.127447,-0.948981 47.125865,-0.948527 47.124269,-0.951528 47.123316,-0.952133 47.120092,-0.9461889999999999 47.120618,-0.946038 47.119935,-0.949882 47.117637,-0.950936 47.115496,-0.9536829999999999 47.114413,-0.95651 47.11443,-0.961096 47.116071,-0.965263 47.115767,-0.964548 47.114124,-0.9672539999999999 47.109873,-0.96705 47.108872,-0.967849 47.107754,-0.970367 47.106898,-0.96872 47.105441,-0.966329 47.104755,-0.969109 47.101294,-0.978438 47.100071,-0.979903 47.096908,-0.984779 47.094839,-0.989408 47.091092,-0.9921 47.09038,-0.99311 47.089019,-0.997895 47.09084,-0.9984960000000001 47.088622,-0.997505 47.086696,-0.998069 47.085131,-0.996599 47.08316,-1.001639 47.082483,-1.004834 47.080101,-1.008233 47.080038,-1.012071 47.07765,-1.013411 47.075481,-1.017289 47.074766,-1.023597 47.077407,-1.026835 47.077853,-1.030644 47.072867,-1.032601 47.071583,-1.032856 47.070107,-1.038363 47.068104,-1.038371 47.067549,-1.039566 47.067823,-1.035791 47.070638,-1.039291 47.07315,-1.041014 47.073183,-1.046194 47.068615,-1.042919 47.063977,-1.04296 47.059505,-1.03872 47.061387,-1.031558 47.055852,-1.040741 47.052037,-1.042479 47.052727,-1.043862 47.052359,-1.041309 47.050274,-1.040363 47.048076,-1.040996 47.047222,-1.038031 47.045406,-1.033921 47.044428,-1.028526 47.046577,-1.028338 47.043193,-1.023855 47.042567,-1.023727 47.044304,-1.022619 47.044506,-1.020078 47.042246,-1.020713 47.0395,-1.018823 47.038146,-1.020219 47.0374,-1.017553 47.03602,-1.011849 47.034329,-1.011117 47.034892,-1.012478 47.036518,-1.012062 47.037209,-1.010507 47.036397,-1.008813 47.037094,-1.005892 47.034645,-1.003499 47.034155,-1.00369 47.029205,-1.008565 47.027608,-1.005871 47.027086,-1.003761 47.02556,-1.001848 47.027837,-1.000034 47.027594,-0.995461 47.024415,-0.9974229999999999 47.022981,-1.000446 47.022611,-0.999402 47.025138,-1.000672 47.02556,-1.002044 47.024403,-1.000567 47.022544,-1.002179 47.02152,-0.999529 47.020687,-0.995514 47.017676,-0.982174 47.010593,-0.980279 47.014309,-0.982976 47.016083,-0.981502 47.017046,-0.981873 47.018124,-0.9783539999999999 47.018918,-0.976156 47.018317,-0.9756629999999999 47.01687,-0.973361 47.016124,-0.975314 47.013218,-0.973166 47.012531,-0.974932 47.010525,-0.975229 47.008652,-0.973483 47.008101,-0.972909 47.009056,-0.970504 47.007588,-0.967816 47.007355,-0.968678 47.006687,-0.965982 47.004729,-0.967052 47.005199,-0.968005 47.004208,-0.966535 47.002838,-0.964014 47.003068,-0.963229 47.001985,-0.963101 47.00063,-0.964984 46.999584,-0.9634470000000001 46.998099,-0.964354 46.997292,-0.963159 46.996458,-0.961741 46.997277,-0.962158 46.995809,-0.959851 46.995287,-0.960803 46.994723,-0.957388 46.994887,-0.9582850000000001 46.99543,-0.9567369999999999 46.996404,-0.954756 46.995966,-0.955661 46.99757,-0.95504 46.999919,-0.953334 47.000764,-0.951958 47.002736,-0.947959 47.003694,-0.948313 47.001307,-0.947166 46.999717,-0.944993 46.998988,-0.941698 47.00358,-0.9402779999999999 47.003189,-0.939812 47.002193,-0.939634 47.002783,-0.938673 47.002401,-0.9385289999999999 47.0034,-0.937296 47.003048,-0.936462 47.005257,-0.934844 47.005633,-0.935539 47.007348,-0.933399 47.009041,-0.9329499999999999 47.007838,-0.932015 47.007985,-0.932389 47.006069,-0.929194 47.008111,-0.927473 47.006346,-0.928248 47.00382,-0.9310389999999999 47.004519,-0.931063 47.003357,-0.9327800000000001 47.00456,-0.935226 47.002345,-0.928661 47.002451,-0.928445 47.000682,-0.925042 46.999834,-0.925021 47.002535,-0.919706 47.003377,-0.919365 47.002324,-0.915853 47.001637,-0.914871 47.000633,-0.916957 46.999858,-0.9179580000000001 46.998454,-0.921435 46.998028,-0.918685 46.996536,-0.918747 46.995522,-0.916525 46.996111,-0.914227 46.994688,-0.915649 46.993302,-0.915289 46.992611,-0.912311 46.992815,-0.910853 46.994271,-0.912372 46.995659,-0.9117 46.995997,-0.908708 46.99287,-0.907873 46.994955,-0.904396 46.994915,-0.902515 46.993922,-0.90103 46.991734,-0.8974839999999999 46.989799,-0.898968 46.988701,-0.895404 46.986335,-0.89623 46.985842,-0.8957270000000001 46.985249,-0.893065 46.984496,-0.8968429999999999 46.980815,-0.8948739999999999 46.980231,-0.8950709999999999 46.979177,-0.8924840000000001 46.978577,-0.892187 46.976082,-0.89028 46.975818,-0.891964 46.97582,-0.88901 46.970996,-0.877125 46.968538,-0.883595 46.962369,-0.877139 46.955856,-0.8837970000000001 46.950389,-0.8835662511166233 46.95026))'::GEOMETRY),
            ('b', 'POLYGON((-1.003499 47.034155,-1.005892 47.034645,-1.008813 47.037094,-1.010507 47.036397,-1.012062 47.037209,-1.012478 47.036518,-1.011117 47.034892,-1.011849 47.034329,-1.017553 47.03602,-1.020219 47.0374,-1.018823 47.038146,-1.020713 47.0395,-1.020078 47.042246,-1.022619 47.044506,-1.023727 47.044304,-1.023855 47.042567,-1.028338 47.043193,-1.028526 47.046577,-1.033921 47.044428,-1.038031 47.045406,-1.040996 47.047222,-1.040363 47.048076,-1.041309 47.050274,-1.043862 47.052359,-1.042479 47.052727,-1.040741 47.052037,-1.031558 47.055852,-1.03872 47.061387,-1.04296 47.059505,-1.042919 47.063977,-1.046194 47.068615,-1.041014 47.073183,-1.039291 47.07315,-1.035791 47.070638,-1.039566 47.067823,-1.038371 47.067549,-1.038363 47.068104,-1.032856 47.070107,-1.032601 47.071583,-1.030644 47.072867,-1.026835 47.077853,-1.023597 47.077407,-1.017289 47.074766,-1.013411 47.075481,-1.012071 47.07765,-1.008233 47.080038,-1.004834 47.080101,-1.001639 47.082483,-0.996599 47.08316,-0.998069 47.085131,-0.997505 47.086696,-0.9984960000000001 47.088622,-0.997895 47.09084,-0.99311 47.089019,-0.9921 47.09038,-0.989408 47.091092,-0.984779 47.094839,-0.979903 47.096908,-0.978438 47.100071,-0.969109 47.101294,-0.966329 47.104755,-0.96872 47.105441,-0.970367 47.106898,-0.967849 47.107754,-0.96705 47.108872,-0.9672539999999999 47.109873,-0.964548 47.114124,-0.965263 47.115767,-0.961096 47.116071,-0.95651 47.11443,-0.9536829999999999 47.114413,-0.950936 47.115496,-0.949882 47.117637,-0.946038 47.119935,-0.9461889999999999 47.120618,-0.952133 47.120092,-0.951528 47.123316,-0.948527 47.124269,-0.948981 47.125865,-0.946984 47.127447,-0.950375 47.129795,-0.948274 47.131818,-0.948601 47.132549,-0.954873 47.135147,-0.956686 47.136964,-0.956129 47.13727,-0.957614 47.13712,-0.956323 47.139477,-0.955037 47.144178,-0.955456 47.144794,-0.948285 47.149339,-0.944708 47.149874,-0.944796 47.151628,-0.941596 47.152113,-0.942047 47.153084,-0.940044 47.153671,-0.940798 47.154856,-0.938397 47.157361,-0.937325 47.157219,-0.934443 47.160325,-0.92893 47.162757,-0.927214 47.162774,-0.926071 47.163675,-0.918746 47.159644,-0.911496 47.159322,-0.910135 47.159648,-0.912727 47.164685,-0.911125 47.164967,-0.908851 47.160224,-0.906819 47.161096,-0.904825 47.161118,-0.90419 47.160098,-0.902938 47.161005,-0.899084 47.160432,-0.895814 47.161263,-0.888682 47.160368,-0.885042 47.158851,-0.879756 47.159392,-0.877381 47.158906,-0.875957 47.159696,-0.874066 47.158261,-0.866803 47.156878,-0.866328 47.154278,-0.863144 47.151598,-0.860479 47.151358,-0.855811 47.152801,-0.851464 47.152844,-0.839548 47.149972,-0.836781 47.150523,-0.831657 47.150077,-0.830325 47.152719,-0.827803 47.152363,-0.825337 47.156855,-0.821728 47.15623,-0.8180539999999999 47.154176,-0.808284 47.157468,-0.805691 47.156591,-0.802353 47.157038,-0.8017 47.153203,-0.7999000000000001 47.151605,-0.798743 47.152046,-0.79675 47.150273,-0.796446 47.14782,-0.792366 47.147384,-0.790662 47.148312,-0.789696 47.147616,-0.788176 47.149197,-0.786251 47.146968,-0.785197 47.146892,-0.784825 47.142603,-0.776545 47.14425,-0.775934 47.142725,-0.76298 47.14355,-0.765204 47.138177,-0.7646810000000001 47.137155,-0.765193 47.13241,-0.764166 47.130843,-0.757279 47.129441,-0.755615 47.126224,-0.753305 47.128401,-0.747465 47.126936,-0.743658 47.127853,-0.7403110000000001 47.130005,-0.727239 47.1286,-0.726214 47.127882,-0.722145 47.128122,-0.719932 47.128783,-0.719769 47.130794,-0.715656 47.132769,-0.7106 47.13282,-0.706937 47.130723,-0.705908 47.131881,-0.703497 47.131179,-0.701852 47.130356,-0.7014899999999999 47.127601,-0.699315 47.1292,-0.696088 47.129613,-0.694172 47.130908,-0.6924630000000001 47.129899,-0.688837 47.129736,-0.685009 47.131849,-0.679654 47.130824,-0.678609 47.129982,-0.671374 47.132367,-0.6700739999999999 47.134202,-0.666837 47.133182,-0.659606 47.136733,-0.661117 47.137602,-0.660788 47.138781,-0.662358 47.13973,-0.661645 47.142495,-0.660958 47.141474,-0.6591669999999999 47.141034,-0.657647 47.141996,-0.657742 47.141094,-0.65679 47.140824,-0.655244 47.141967,-0.655204 47.144456,-0.650964 47.14514,-0.650943 47.144014,-0.6502289999999999 47.144351,-0.648071 47.146159,-0.648111 47.148068,-0.645837 47.148712,-0.6429009999999999 47.150853,-0.641321 47.15116,-0.637368 47.149049,-0.636791 47.151277,-0.634778 47.151401,-0.614066 47.148949,-0.611255 47.147944,-0.608714 47.151739,-0.6064310000000001 47.153063,-0.606321 47.153981,-0.60299 47.157147,-0.598875 47.159885,-0.596559 47.163645,-0.593306 47.166566,-0.5911419999999999 47.169356,-0.590948 47.173115,-0.589552 47.175159,-0.581188 47.180057,-0.571555 47.189365,-0.565194 47.192525,-0.558835 47.194163,-0.557256 47.197598,-0.555665 47.199108,-0.555934 47.200523,-0.550243 47.20432,-0.547078 47.208665,-0.544078 47.207204,-0.533786 47.207824,-0.518344 47.210022,-0.506224 47.209061,-0.500894 47.20962,-0.497523 47.211184,-0.495366 47.210041,-0.493161 47.210967,-0.48982 47.2108,-0.479899 47.208412,-0.480932 47.206143,-0.483332 47.20406,-0.482276 47.200104,-0.48129 47.199278,-0.480203 47.199556,-0.478934 47.198011,-0.476512 47.198431,-0.473101 47.197326,-0.46267 47.206468,-0.461469 47.206421,-0.455677 47.211151,-0.453324 47.216126,-0.454212 47.218059,-0.448277 47.221702,-0.443709 47.220465,-0.439494 47.215173,-0.436489 47.21435,-0.432012 47.215171,-0.430493 47.214774,-0.42749 47.218448,-0.423234 47.221124,-0.421213 47.223417,-0.417328 47.223194,-0.408793 47.219609,-0.401168 47.219627,-0.401814 47.215326,-0.40383 47.213639,-0.405048 47.210537,-0.407826 47.206784,-0.410264 47.206932,-0.41171 47.205248,-0.409833 47.204575,-0.412285 47.201901,-0.412792 47.200155,-0.418511 47.195844,-0.418248 47.193134,-0.417619 47.190956,-0.413958 47.190365,-0.413439 47.187417,-0.412285 47.187333,-0.412716 47.185433,-0.411996 47.185065,-0.411807 47.183143,-0.413784 47.180231,-0.407773 47.179534,-0.402195 47.177222,-0.399488 47.177426,-0.397269 47.174935,-0.394587 47.176119,-0.38967 47.175879,-0.394179 47.171043,-0.406628 47.163987,-0.410125 47.158827,-0.404906 47.160023,-0.40023 47.155858,-0.399628 47.159767,-0.396127 47.159938,-0.384412 47.156495,-0.375187 47.151642,-0.369563 47.153469,-0.366432 47.151314,-0.36114 47.151223,-0.35578 47.149185,-0.353323 47.152762,-0.351485 47.152225,-0.352047 47.151282,-0.350341 47.148346,-0.350786 47.146715,-0.348841 47.146936,-0.347566 47.146139,-0.353369 47.141311,-0.350545 47.13761,-0.342742 47.134635,-0.338095 47.134994,-0.333255 47.133742,-0.334297 47.132289,-0.332489 47.131577,-0.33382 47.130432,-0.337955 47.130561,-0.341232 47.128987,-0.339153 47.12661,-0.339118 47.125369,-0.338209 47.125162,-0.33722 47.12614,-0.332498 47.125027,-0.330249 47.126144,-0.3293 47.12564,-0.330002 47.123199,-0.327816 47.122427,-0.325581 47.123121,-0.321459 47.121283,-0.323874 47.116436,-0.322166 47.113341,-0.322738 47.108762,-0.318197 47.107497,-0.317185 47.108012,-0.314916 47.106305,-0.315605 47.105394,-0.311854 47.104175,-0.312555 47.092257,-0.335593 47.087996,-0.341764 47.087377,-0.342071 47.089257,-0.340917 47.092061,-0.349764 47.091708,-0.353789 47.095386,-0.359845 47.093259,-0.368792 47.091703,-0.370858 47.090185,-0.376532 47.088641,-0.380109 47.09001,-0.381368 47.08822,-0.384549 47.087401,-0.386349 47.087343,-0.387114 47.092276,-0.396159 47.091638,-0.396735 47.08308,-0.400268 47.074938,-0.401197 47.070748,-0.407124 47.066498,-0.409291 47.066201,-0.417558 47.070664,-0.418326 47.071955,-0.423197 47.069714,-0.424254 47.071464,-0.425664 47.07098,-0.425819 47.072494,-0.426981 47.072988,-0.438973 47.069898,-0.439206 47.068855,-0.441123 47.067722,-0.45469 47.067357,-0.458225 47.068988,-0.460605 47.06816,-0.461078 47.068813,-0.465024 47.066888,-0.471237 47.059795,-0.472096 47.057572,-0.476341 47.054362,-0.48032 47.053338,-0.485332 47.063885,-0.484992 47.065973,-0.478094 47.071911,-0.472027 47.072332,-0.469805 47.073652,-0.468249 47.073194,-0.464185 47.074359,-0.463973 47.076088,-0.458991 47.079943,-0.459531 47.082046,-0.464456 47.081975,-0.468364 47.083816,-0.473271 47.081777,-0.476073 47.083041,-0.478752 47.081727,-0.484783 47.081687,-0.487739 47.080881,-0.490791 47.082896,-0.493101 47.083353,-0.504174 47.079332,-0.507317 47.079241,-0.511785 47.077466,-0.51525 47.078035,-0.525741 47.073919,-0.535313 47.0722,-0.544635 47.068135,-0.546309 47.066274,-0.557553 47.06409,-0.559461 47.061813,-0.5567 47.060691,-0.5543709999999999 47.05726,-0.558239 47.056069,-0.558275 47.053228,-0.556006 47.044378,-0.556265 47.042695,-0.548737 47.04057,-0.542042 47.034972,-0.542997 47.033622,-0.542336 47.032532,-0.54533 47.030668,-0.54581 47.029103,-0.547006 47.028835,-0.547965 47.029652,-0.551732 47.029048,-0.555679 47.030902,-0.562342 47.030496,-0.564087 47.026005,-0.563775 47.02414,-0.564869 47.020141,-0.569053 47.018291,-0.574987 47.017828,-0.580904 47.014612,-0.587014 47.009192,-0.586932 47.006709,-0.58775 47.005337,-0.594749 47.002794,-0.597171 47.000769,-0.593961 46.998759,-0.5954930000000001 46.99791,-0.601611 46.997764,-0.618781 46.992342,-0.621938 46.993911,-0.6249400000000001 46.992792,-0.624561 46.994115,-0.6279169999999999 46.995691,-0.6267430000000001 46.996879,-0.63266 46.997508,-0.6354379999999999 46.995724,-0.640352 46.996116,-0.641046 46.994672,-0.642167 46.994818,-0.645504 46.99212,-0.646962 46.992308,-0.646391 46.99368,-0.649992 46.994917,-0.648025 46.996594,-0.650398 46.997689,-0.653462 46.997772,-0.657311 46.999199,-0.657708 46.9986,-0.660979 46.998839,-0.661627 46.997686,-0.669937 47.000802,-0.670368 47.002636,-0.671843 47.003185,-0.674719 47.001621,-0.676179 47.001885,-0.676831 47.000296,-0.674732 46.999172,-0.676007 46.997074,-0.675567 46.996648,-0.68038 46.993238,-0.678529 46.992114,-0.677686 46.989976,-0.680188 46.987659,-0.6829809999999999 46.98842,-0.686887 46.988065,-0.689599 46.990414,-0.689629 46.993058,-0.693412 46.992411,-0.696663 46.994873,-0.698748 46.99461,-0.700809 46.992531,-0.70435 46.992196,-0.703637 46.991424,-0.704682 46.990212,-0.712202 46.986674,-0.715947 46.98402,-0.7181070000000001 46.987193,-0.72926 46.995934,-0.7325430000000001 46.997508,-0.739475 46.998787,-0.743405 47.000992,-0.743626 46.994335,-0.74298 46.992012,-0.747754 46.991537,-0.753551 46.992972,-0.756819 46.991958,-0.7615150000000001 46.992264,-0.76411 46.992997,-0.765475 46.994016,-0.76528 46.994815,-0.7670979999999999 46.995785,-0.768885 46.995031,-0.768693 46.998337,-0.767998 46.99898,-0.768472 47.001449,-0.769335 47.002974,-0.771352 47.003471,-0.772268 47.004577,-0.773718 47.004606,-0.776458 47.003002,-0.7780010000000001 47.00428,-0.779699 47.004275,-0.781774 47.002141,-0.783438 47.001813,-0.784541 47.002807,-0.784486 47.004214,-0.786724 47.005452,-0.78967 47.003752,-0.789635 47.002406,-0.791189 47.0001,-0.796264 46.996051,-0.800662 46.994378,-0.804104 46.99387,-0.807032 46.994405,-0.810871 46.991732,-0.809145 46.99059,-0.808373 46.991571,-0.805102 46.989541,-0.807346 46.988608,-0.808466 46.986718,-0.809551 46.988562,-0.812299 46.989251,-0.812597 46.990568,-0.815701 46.989765,-0.811339 46.991774,-0.811747 46.994549,-0.815426 46.993264,-0.817527 46.993124,-0.81869 46.994079,-0.826568 46.992643,-0.8363429999999999 46.985762,-0.839504 46.985428,-0.842993 46.990173,-0.846592 46.986729,-0.847436 46.986872,-0.847915 46.982014,-0.849641 46.981979,-0.857129 46.978461,-0.85654 46.977397,-0.8492420000000001 46.97382,-0.8526 46.971008,-0.854617 46.971188,-0.860658 46.968886,-0.861437 46.969427,-0.861169 46.970234,-0.862803 46.970306,-0.862043 46.971125,-0.863063 46.971487,-0.863054 46.972617,-0.866704 46.973134,-0.867239 46.972541,-0.868179 46.973273,-0.869896 46.972059,-0.872356 46.973921,-0.87925 46.974666,-0.880167 46.975259,-0.879569 46.976065,-0.882064 46.977455,-0.882176 46.976556,-0.884937 46.977334,-0.8851560000000001 46.976298,-0.886918 46.976492,-0.888462 46.975566,-0.892187 46.976082,-0.8924840000000001 46.978577,-0.8950709999999999 46.979177,-0.8948739999999999 46.980231,-0.8968429999999999 46.980815,-0.893065 46.984496,-0.8957270000000001 46.985249,-0.89623 46.985842,-0.895404 46.986335,-0.898968 46.988701,-0.8974839999999999 46.989799,-0.90103 46.991734,-0.902515 46.993922,-0.904396 46.994915,-0.907873 46.994955,-0.908708 46.99287,-0.9117 46.995997,-0.912372 46.995659,-0.910853 46.994271,-0.912311 46.992815,-0.915289 46.992611,-0.915649 46.993302,-0.914227 46.994688,-0.916525 46.996111,-0.918747 46.995522,-0.918685 46.996536,-0.921435 46.998028,-0.9179580000000001 46.998454,-0.916957 46.999858,-0.914871 47.000633,-0.915853 47.001637,-0.919365 47.002324,-0.919706 47.003377,-0.925021 47.002535,-0.925042 46.999834,-0.928445 47.000682,-0.928661 47.002451,-0.935226 47.002345,-0.9327800000000001 47.00456,-0.931063 47.003357,-0.9310389999999999 47.004519,-0.928248 47.00382,-0.927473 47.006346,-0.929194 47.008111,-0.932389 47.006069,-0.932015 47.007985,-0.9329499999999999 47.007838,-0.933399 47.009041,-0.935539 47.007348,-0.934844 47.005633,-0.936462 47.005257,-0.937296 47.003048,-0.9385289999999999 47.0034,-0.938673 47.002401,-0.939634 47.002783,-0.939812 47.002193,-0.9402779999999999 47.003189,-0.941698 47.00358,-0.944993 46.998988,-0.947166 46.999717,-0.948313 47.001307,-0.947959 47.003694,-0.951958 47.002736,-0.953334 47.000764,-0.95504 46.999919,-0.955661 46.99757,-0.954756 46.995966,-0.9567369999999999 46.996404,-0.9582850000000001 46.99543,-0.957388 46.994887,-0.960803 46.994723,-0.959851 46.995287,-0.962158 46.995809,-0.961741 46.997277,-0.963159 46.996458,-0.964354 46.997292,-0.9634470000000001 46.998099,-0.964984 46.999584,-0.963101 47.00063,-0.963229 47.001985,-0.964014 47.003068,-0.966535 47.002838,-0.968005 47.004208,-0.967052 47.005199,-0.965982 47.004729,-0.968678 47.006687,-0.967816 47.007355,-0.970504 47.007588,-0.972909 47.009056,-0.973483 47.008101,-0.975229 47.008652,-0.974932 47.010525,-0.973166 47.012531,-0.975314 47.013218,-0.973361 47.016124,-0.9756629999999999 47.01687,-0.976156 47.018317,-0.9783539999999999 47.018918,-0.981873 47.018124,-0.981502 47.017046,-0.982976 47.016083,-0.980279 47.014309,-0.982174 47.010593,-0.995514 47.017676,-0.999529 47.020687,-1.002179 47.02152,-1.000567 47.022544,-1.002044 47.024403,-1.000672 47.02556,-0.999402 47.025138,-1.000446 47.022611,-0.9974229999999999 47.022981,-0.995461 47.024415,-1.000034 47.027594,-1.001848 47.027837,-1.003761 47.02556,-1.005871 47.027086,-1.008565 47.027608,-1.00369 47.029205,-1.003499 47.034155))'::GEOMETRY)
    )
SELECT  GeometryType(dmp.geom) AS gt, COUNT(*)
FROM    z AS a, z AS b,
        LATERAL ST_Dump(ST_Intersection(ST_Difference(a.geom, b.geom), b.geom)) AS dmp
GROUP BY
        1
;

     gt     | count 
------------+-------
 POLYGON    |     1
 LINESTRING |   458
(2 rows)
```

This is also true **for the exact geometries of the linked GitHub issue**.

*For reference, this is produced on* ***`POSTGIS 3.0.0` |  `GEOS 3.8.0`***

---

*To clarify the relationship assumptions on the PostGIS level:*

The `ST_Difference` for *non-overlapping* (but potentially *touching*) `A` & `B` geometries **is (spatially equal to) `A`**, [since](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Difference.html)

> [...] ST_Difference(A, B) always returns a portion of A.

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Difference('POLYGON((0 0, 1 0, 1 1, 0 1, 0 0))'::GEOMETRY, 'POLYGON((1 0, 2 0, 2 1, 1 1, 1 0))'::GEOMETRY));

           st_astext            
--------------------------------
 POLYGON((1 0,0 0,0 1,1 1,1 0))
(1 row)
```

and an `ST_Intersection` between the above **with `B`** is the common *boundary* (as per the [DE-9IM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DE-9IM) definition) as in an `ST_Intersection` of `A` & `B`; i.e. with `ST_Difference`:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Intersection(ST_Difference('POLYGON((0 0, 1 0, 1 1, 0 1, 0 0))'::GEOMETRY, 'POLYGON((1 0, 2 0, 2 1, 1 1, 1 0))'::GEOMETRY), 'POLYGON((1 0, 2 0, 2 1, 1 1, 1 0))'::GEOMETRY));

      st_astext      
---------------------
 LINESTRING(1 1,1 0)
(1 row)
```

and with only `ST_Intersects`:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Intersection('POLYGON((0 0, 1 0, 1 1, 0 1, 0 0))'::GEOMETRY, 'POLYGON((1 0, 2 0, 2 1, 1 1, 1 0))'::GEOMETRY));

      st_astext      
---------------------
 LINESTRING(1 0,1 1)
(1 row)
```

**EXCEPT**, unfortunately, for cases with **floating point imprecision** (between geometries with non-matching vertices).

Note here that, with PostGIS 3.1 most spatial relationship construction functions (e.g. `ST_Difference` & `ST_Intersection`) come with an additional parameter `gridSize`, which, when set, snaps the inputs

> [...] to a grid of the given size, and the result vertices are computed on that same grid.

which helps getting exact matches for when *non-matching* vertices are in snapping distance from each other.

---

**Update:**

One possible solution to correct the topology; derive the `ST_Intersection` and `ST_Difference` **of an `ST_Union` of `A` & `B`**  with either `A` **or** `B`, to be used as base geometries `A'` & `B'`:

```
SELECT  GeometryType(dmp.geom) AS gt, COUNT(*)
FROM    (
    SELECT  ST_Intersection(ST_Union(a.geom, b.geom), a.geom) AS geom_with_name_a,
            ST_Difference(ST_Union(a.geom, b.geom), ST_Intersection(ST_Union(a.geom, b.geom), a.geom)) AS geom_with_name_b
    FROM    z a, z b
    WHERE   a.name = 'a' and b.name = 'b'
) q, LATERAL ST_Dump(ST_Intersection(ST_Difference(geom_with_name_a, geom_with_name_b), geom_with_name_b)) AS dmp
GROUP BY
        1
;

     gt       | count 
--------------+-------
 LINESTRING   |   461
(1 row)
```

Result type is `MULTILINESTRING` and represents the complete common *boundary* of both geometries.

Comment: Updated with a solution applicable for (topologically incorrect) adjacent polygons with shared borders.

Comment: Thank you that very complete answer! It will for sure help me. However I do not understand why I didn't see the `POLYGON` in the result. The way I searched for it was by copying the result and `grep -i poly`..

Comment: Copied from IDE/client? Probably didn't get the full string length there...

Comment: Yeah that is what I though but I get a valid `GEOMETRYCOLLECTION` when I copy.. (https://pastebin.com/CZ0HirLL)

Comment: That is weird - do you get the same results when running the `ST_Dump` as above?

Comment: No, I have 2 polygons and 918 linestrings.

Unfortunately I'm on heroku, hence I cannot upgrade POSTGIS that easily..

Comment: Yeah, that's just because of the *cross product* of your implicit `CROSS JOIN`; your query runs the operations on `a b` and `b a` - forgot the `WHERE`? Better use the explicit `JOIN` syntax to identify these kinds of errors. -> Divide that number by 2 and you get 459.